# WixSharp - Specifying order for a ManageAction to run when there are multiple

Tags: action, wixsharp

I've been using ManagedActionand and ElevatedManagedAction for sometime and everything has been great; however, I have a need now to execute actions in a particular order, or at least ensure actions are done first/last as may be necessary.

I assumed that actions were executed in the order entered for example:

```
 Project project =
    new Project("My Project",
        new Property("SOME_PROPERTY", "ABC"),
        new Dir(@"%ProgramFiles%\blah blah blah",
            new File(...),
            ...

        new ManagedAction(CustomActions.FirstAction, ...) {},
        ...

        new ManagedAction(CustomActions.LastAction, ...) {}
        ...
```

I have a number of actions and so then thought, well ... , maybe bottom up, so I put what I wanted to run first at the bottom. That didn't change the order, so then I thought maybe alphabetical and did a couple of tests and sure enough that's what it did.

So, is there another way to specify the order actions are called other than adding a prefix for the name of the action, like A01_FirstAction, A02_LastAction ...?

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is!

```
project.Actions = new WixSharp.Action[] {
  new ManagedAction(CustomActions.MyFirstCustomAction,Return.check, When.Before, Step.InstallFinalize, Condition.NOT_Installed),
  new ManagedAction(CustomActions.MySecondCustomAction,Return.check, When.After, Step.PreviousAction, Condition.NOT_Installed),
  new ManagedAction(CustomActions.MyThirdCustomAction,Return.check, When.After, Step.PreviousAction, Condition.NOT_Installed)
}
```

Just take a look at the 2 parameters `When` and `Step`. In this case the first `ManagedAction` will be executed **Before** the step **InstallFinalize**. The second `ManagedAction` will be executed **After** the **PreviousAction**. This means after the previous action defined in the array. Same goes with the last `ManagedAction`. That's the way I figured out to specify an order.

Hope this helps.